# setData - How to pass my data from a function in the Code Behind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, heatmap

I am using the Heatmap.js library to create a map overlay on top of Google maps. It works great as long as I hard-code the data within my  tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.20, -90.50);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 5,
center: myLatlng
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("MyMap"), myOptions);
// heatmap layer
heatmap = new HeatmapOverlay(map,{
radius: 15,
maxOpacity: 0.6,
minOpacity: 0.6,
blur: 0,
gradient: {'0':'Green', '0.75':'yellow', '1':'Red'},
scaleRadius: false,
useLocalExtrema: false,
latField: 'lat',
lngField: 'lng',
valueField: 'value'
});

var init = { max: 2, data: [{ lat: 35.6408, lng: -90.7728, value: 1.2},
{ lat: 37.6408, lng: -92.7728, value: 4.8},
{ lat: 36.9438, lng: -91.7428, value: 0.2}]};
heatmap.setData(init);
</script>
```

However, what I am trying to do is to use JQuery to call a function in the code behind (VB) and use the returned value to feed the data. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#updateMap").click(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "Default.aspx/getPIAFData",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
    heatmap.setData({ max: 2, data: [data] });
    },});});});
```

My function in the code behind returns a string, which I can see (via alert();) that's returning the correct characters. However, the Heatmap.js setData function expects an array of objects:

```
var data = {
    max: 10,
    data: [{datapoint1, datapoint2, datapoint3, etc}]};
```

Each datapoint comprises of {lat: 1234, lng: 1234, value: 1234}.

I need to either find a way to parse the return string into the correct format for Heatmaps.js or change my function in the code behind to return the right array of objects. Anyone with experience working with Heatmaps.js library getting the data from another function (code behind)?

Thank you very much.
PC

Comment: what is the string?  is it JSON?  maybe you just need to JSON.parse() the data?

Comment: James, sorry for the delay in acknowledging your comment. I was able to make it work yesterday after a lot of trial and error. Essentially, here is how it's working now:

Comment: <not enough time for editing>

James, sorry for the delay in acknowledging your comment. I was able to make it work yesterday after a lot of trial and error. Essentially, here is how it's working now:

- My code behind (VB) function still returns a string. However, I had to use two double quotes when building my string. I was alternating double and single quotes and that wasn't helping at all.
- Once I receive the string message back in my Javascript side, I do use a JSON.parse(msg.d) where msg is the string returned by the VB function.

Thank you for your help and comment.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  You do indeed need double quotes for valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work after a lot of trial and error. Essentially, here is how it's working now:

- My code behind (VB) function still returns a string. However, I had to use two double quotes when building my string. I was alternating double and single quotes and that wasn't helping at all.
- Once I receive the string message back in my Javascript side, I do use a JSON.parse(msg.d) where msg is the string returned by the VB function.